# adding action listener for the node in a tree

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, jtree

I am unable to add action listener to a particular node in the tree. This is a tree that i've constructed :

[image]

I want to register a separate listener for each node . Now i have registered a listener on `JTree`. so, whenever i click on any portion of `tree` the listener method starts it's work. *(i.e now i have a common listener )*
What i want is when i click on *audio* a listener registered to hear audio click, should start it's work and the same goes for video. **How can i do that ?**

This is how i have registered so far :

```
jTree1.addTreeSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
            jTree1ValueChanged(evt);
        }
    });
public void jTree1ValueChanged( TreeSelectionEvent tse ) {...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this. Or do you have special PathComponents?

```
public void jTree1ValueChanged( TreeSelectionEvent tse ) {
     String node = tse.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent().toString();
    if( node.equals("audio") ) {
        // play audio
    } else if( node.equals("video") ) {
       // play video
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it solved my problem . But can you please tell what does `getNewLeadSelectionPath` return ? Doc says `Returns the current lead path` but i don't understand what it means.

Comment: And also the method `getLastPathComponent`. What does it actually return?

Comment: A TreePath in a JTree contains a list of TreeNode starting from the tree root, a child node A of the root, a child node of A, and so on. The type of these children is determined by the underlying TreeModel. For DefaultTreeModel, they are TreeNode objects. The lead selection path is the path to the node that has the focus (at least in BasicTreeUI), so in your case probably the one that the user clicked on. This node is also the last component in the path.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an event listener to tree-node because the class representing the tree-node is not a Component.